# Siri Shortcuts Response Templates Not Working

Tags: ios, ios12, siri, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I have shortcuts up and running and I have my custom response added to my completion handler. In this case...

```
  completion ([TriggerSceneIntentResponse successIntentResponseWithSceneName:intent.sceneName]);
```

When I ask Siri to run my shortcut I get success but all she says is "Done", or "OK".  My template for success is *"Your sceneName scene has been activated."* However again, Siri never uses this template for some reason.

I'm not sure if image posts are working in the forums but I'll give it a try here. Here's what my custom intent looks like in the intent editor.

[image]

And here is what Siri is saying back...

[image]

Again, as you can see, she's just saying *"Done"*. When she should be saying, *"Your Laundry Room Off 101 scene has been activated."*

I've confirmed that my completion line above is called by debugging my intent target. I'm unsure what I'm missing?

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same issue and managed to fix it by localizing the intent definition file. I believe Siri won't be able to respond if your device and project supported langages don't match.

On the right panel in the screenshot you'll have to click on the localized button. Select supported langages, it will create sub-intent files where you can localize your strings.

[image: Here's what it looks like with Apple's SoupChef project]

Comment: I was stuck with this issue. Your solution worked for me. Thank u

Comment: I was fighting quite some time, this answer really helped me. Even if your Base language is the only one you support you need to add a localization for your supported language (probably only if it different from english).

Comment: Thank you for this. You saved me.

Comment: Thank you! You save my day :D

Answer (score 0):

There are two relevant methods in your `TriggerSceneIntentHandler`. One is `confirmIntent...` and the other `handleIntent...`.

Make sure you are calling the completion handler with the success in the `handleIntent...` method.